# Error opening terminal: unknown Qt Creator on MacOs 10.12.4

Tags: c++, macos, qt, terminal, cmake

I have installed QtCreator (4.2.2) and cmake (3.8.1) through homebrew on Mac OS 10.12.4.

I am importing an existing CMake project but when QtCreator is running cmake, I encounter the following error:

```
Running "/usr/local/bin/ccmake /Users/matthieu/project/source '-GCodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/g++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/gcc '-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=%{Qt:QT_INSTALL_PREFIX}' -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=" in /Users/matthieu/project/source/build-decaf-Desktop-Default.
Error opening terminal: unknown.
```

In QtCreator > Preferences > Environment > System, the terminal is set to:
`/Applications/Qt\ Creator.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/scripts/openTerminal.command`

My `TERM` env variable is set to `xterm-256color`. I have tried `xterm-color` as well but with no luck.

I start to run out of ideas if someone has any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your Qt Creator build settings have been set up to point at `ccmake` instead of `cmake` as the CMake executable. Have a look in the *Build & Run* section under the *CMake* tab and see what executable has been set. The `cmake` executable is the command line tool that you want, `ccmake` is a curses-based UI front end to CMake meant for interactive editing of the CMake cache.

Comment: Oh ya, that was it! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

The TERM isn't being recognized. Try stepping down to something more common, like

TERM=xterm

Comment: Same result with changing both the ENV variable and in QtCreator preferences.